# Fix issue with displaced braces( )

Tags: formatting

I have a problem with the output and placement of braces `()`. When braces occur in code, it is displayed wrongly in the output.

Can any one solve this problem ?

```
<?php echo "I am (developer)"; ?>
```

Here developer is enclosed with braces, the output of the above code is as follow

> (I am (developer

rather than

> I am (developer)

How This problem occure

**EDIT**

I have install polylang plugin to change RTL TO LTR .But after deleting plugin still face problem. This is effecting my whole site. I've made a lot functionality in my site and the effect is everywhere where I have brace() like post title,post content etc

Comment: Where do you include the code?

Comment: I am using woocommrerce plugin and subcategories (title having count) let's an example shirts(10) and products levis(mens).I also check using in archive-product.php and get some problem again for check in theme I create a page from admin and write in content area I am (developer) and same problem.

Comment: So you are using this in template or content editor or what? WP content editor does not support PHP natively.

Comment: I use it in pages I got that problem.That is not php problem.I thing its wordpress problem

Comment: I use in page content editor without php code also I use in header.php without php same error occure

Comment: I suspect from your previous question that you are using a rtl language, which will explain this behavior of the braces

Comment: No this is a separate question.

Comment: I know, but is your website set up for a rtl language.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem caused by switching a site from LTR to RTL and vice-versa. I've tested it as well, here is my output if I switch my site to RTL

```
<?php echo "I am (developer)"; ?>
```

renders

> (I am (developer

This is normal behavior when you switch to a RTL language. The problem is, [parentheses or simply `()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) doesn't have any direction. When only one `(` is used as in this

```
<?php echo "I am (developer"; ?>
```

it output correctly as

> I am (developer

When the second parentheses appear, then things go haywire. Because of no inhereted direction, the browser simply reverse direction of the second parentheses, in this case `)`, in runs into, and paste in right at the front of the sentence, this is what you see in you question

To correct that, you need to 'tell' the browser somehow about this direction issue in order to output the text in the correct order of characters. This is where the [**left-to-right mark** (LRM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) is used. For more on implementation, [read here](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H34.html)

> It is used to set the way adjacent characters are grouped with respect to text direction.

The characters to use `&lrm;` or `&#x200e;`, so will do something like this

```
<?php echo "I am (developer)&lrm;"; ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo "I am (developer)&#x200e;"; ?>
```

**EDIT 1**

It seems like from your link it might be caused in normal LTR. You then have to use the [**right-to-left mark (RLM)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark). It uses the following: `&rlm;` or `&#x200f;`

So you will need to do the following

```
<?php echo "I am (developer)&rlm;"; ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo "I am (developer)&#x200f;"; ?>
```

**EDIT 2**

Ifyou need to replace `)` in your titles, you can use the [`the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) filter to get all instances and replace it with [`str-replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). This should go into **functions.php**

```
add_filter('the_title', function ($title) 
{
   return str_replace(')', ')&lrm;', $title);

}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Just test it using the opposite as well

```
add_filter('the_title', function ($title) 
{
   return str_replace(')', ')&rlm;', $title);

}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Comment: It might be the cause of RTL. I install polylang plugin but currently I deactivate it . Here I take an example  got this effect  in subcategories count and product like having title shirt(mens).I mean where there is braces ().IF you like demonstrate I will provide you link may be you understand it clearly.

Comment: Yes I check link that you provide but can't see any code and explanation how to use in web development. Its okay .Can you please tell me procedure how you use RTL to LTR and LTR to RTL.I want to use this option to my user that they can swith language from frontend. What should I need to use

Comment: I just gave you an example. It is as straight forward as placing `&lrm;` after `)`. You should really be able to implement this.

Comment: I want to clear you I had install polylang plugin and Now removed it but I get this problem. I have create a lot of functionality in site like there is subcategory count  and products name a lot more .Can you please tell me how can I resolve this problem.Also in future I have problem if some body is not aware with this thing It will be a problem.Also &lrm; if I use it can be possible only for static not for dynamic cuase I know is there ) or not.

Comment: Please **edit** your question and add an example of function

Comment: HERE  IS LINK : [link](http://www.smartzonewebservices.com/dev/wc/product-category/shirts/)
you can check on top and left side bar

Comment: Check update, I added LTR solution

Comment: Where you make update.

Comment: Where it say **EDIT**

Comment: Yes you have edit my post So you mean it's update.

Comment: I see if I use it in wordpress post title how can I do this because post title does't accept html character. Do you how can I remove it completely from my wordpress site

Comment: Please check my **EDIT 2** in **my answer**. This should now do it

Comment: Can I ask you to remove this problem cause I have install woo-commerce plugin as my site is shopping site .
I create number of category with its count number of product in that category shirts(10) and product like v-shirt(women).Also there is a lot of place in my site where there is braces likes pages and articles etc .So Is there a way that I can remove this without writting code every place where there is brace cause there is number of places where braces() use.